# How to Dockerize Jmeter (Distributed testing with Docker and Jmeter)

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, jmeter, dockerfile

I am using the jmeter 5.2 and the plugin 1.4.0. I am trying to dockerize the my automations in jmeter. But i take an error like following;

```
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.assertions.JSONPathAssertion (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

My Docker-compose file;

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  master:
    build: ..
    command: master
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "60000"
    volumes:
      - "./test/:/jmeter/sample/"
    networks:
      - jmeter-network
  server:
    image: pedrocesarti/jmeter-docker:latest
    command: server
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "50000"
      - "1099"
    networks:
      - jmeter-network
    depends_on:
      - master

networks:
  jmeter-network:
```

I've tried a lot of solutions but i cannot resolve this problem. Could you help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any of your application's source code or any part of your Dockerfile that's relevant to the question?  Which container or command is producing that error?  What solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Dockerfile for pedrocesarti/jmeter-docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/pedrocesarti/jmeter-docker/dockerfile)

```
ENV JMETER_VERSION ${JMETER_VERSION:-3.3}
```

and your test seems to be using [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) which is available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4/)

So you need to [replace the JMETER_VERSION variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#environment-replacement) with version `4.0` or higher and your script should start working as expected.